# Is there a way to reduce the search index?

Tags: search

Our search index table (craft_searchindex) is over 500,000 rows and it takes a few hours to index. We have 11 languages, and each is being fully indexed. It takes a few hours to complete.

Are there any ways we can reduce the search index size (e.g. only one language, or specific sections?

Comment: Mine is currently sitting at ~1.1M, taking up around 93MB, or half the database size. This is killing performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Craft 3:**

In Craft 3, a plugin can listen to the `Element::EVENT_REGISTER_SEARCHABLE_ATTRIBUTES` event to modify the searchable attribute list of an element before it is indexed.

**Craft 2:**

Currently the answer is no.

Maybe it [makes the case](http://feedback.craftcms.com) for some sort of `onBeforeSearchIndex` event a plugin could listen to and influence what Craft adds to the search index, but given that manually updating the search index isn't meant to be a common occurrence (Craft keeps them up to date in normal element saving operations), I'd probably add the workflow you're using that requires frequent updates to the feature request.

Comment: Is that for Craft 3 as well?

Comment: @FrankLämmer Updated answer for Craft 3.